# Novel in which the Earth is abandoned and quarantined, but some people remain

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to find a book I had in 80s that I recently realized I have lost.  It was about a war that happened on Earth, forcing people to abandon it.  Once abandoned, a no-go zone was established around Earth, and one rebellious star pilot decides to investigate Earth to understand why, after hundreds of years, it is still considered dangerous.  He discovers a changed planet where some of the humans left behind have changed and some now have magical powers, etc.  The length of the book was above average and the cover featured a man in a spacesuit on Earth, surprised by a creature.

Would be very appreciative of any input regarding the name and author of the book as it was apparently lost during a move.

Comment: Can you give anymore plot or story detail? I have probably read 20 books with a plot simular to what you outlined here.

Comment: As the story continues, the authorities try to keep it a secret that Earth is habitable and may also be thriving.  The main character eventually befriends several of the creatures some of which would resemble elves/dwarves.  The main character is then forced to decide whether to defend them against the authorities who come to rescue him and see the creatures with these powers as a threat and the creatures who see the outworlders as a threat to them and want nothing to do with them and may try to use their powers to keep them from leaving in order to keep others from coming.  I hope that helps.

Comment: There is also a love interest where the female simply wants him to forget the whole and come back before the situation gets out of control.  She also ends up being involved.

Comment: Sounds like it could be any of the stories the evolve from 'The Time Machine' by H. G. Wells. Stories of an Abandoned, lost, destroyed, restricted, etc... Earth abounded in SciFi.  Your description is the standard, no surprises, by the numbers, plot summary; for most of the less memorable ones.  Is there anything that makes it different?

Answer (score 3):

Could it be **Silent Galaxy** by William Tedford?

[http://www.amazon.com/Silent-Galaxy-William-Tedford/dp/0843909978](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0843909978)

> After a nuclear holocaust, the only remains of human civilization are
>   the fledgling space colonies, which adapt and colonize the solar
>   system. A couple of hundred years later, a Jovian fighter pilot
>   crash-lands on Earth after a battle with Luna Nation setting off a
>   chain of events that would take him all across the solar system and
>   possibly lead to the life or death of the human species.